# How to reduce eureka CPU consumption after startup?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, netflix-eureka

I have eureka server running in my aws ec2 instance and after successful startup I see permanent CPU load around 15-20%, I would expect it should be around zero as I have only 3 services registered.

I use eureka tutorials and have tried to play with application.yml file by removing all things which I don't understand, but no luck so far.

== application.yml ==

```
server:
  port: 8000

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false # telling the server not to register himself in the service
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone : http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

I use java 1.8.

== build.gradle ==

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'org.example.eureka'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.withType(Jar) {
    archiveName = "eurekaserver.jar"
}
```

I see the following lines in the log:

```
Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

Most likely I'm missing something in configuration, but don't know what as in google I haven't found relevant hints/settings so far. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used process start in health check command in the task definition. After I fixed that oversight the problem has gone.

Comment: Hello, how did you fix it? Can you share more details? Thanks.